# Linux binary executable properties: ldd alternative?

Tags: linux, libraries

The Linux  ldd command can show the dynamic libraries used by an executable. It's a bash script.
But it seems to be fragile, and does not work on some binaries. Is there an alternative tool?

In my specific example, I can use:

**% file datab2txt**

**datab2txt: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped**

but ldd fails with:

**% ldd -v datab2txt**

**not a dynamic executable**

Comment: The module doesn't depend on dynamically loading any libraries.  The ldd command does work in this case.

Answer (score 9):

You could also do:

```
readelf -d executable | grep NEEDED
```

But this probably doesn't do what you want.  It shows the libs that `executable` links to, but not all the libs it needs (a library can require another library).

Comment: it is also not printing paths to libraries (like ldd)

Answer (score 7):

The output of `file` says "**statically linked**". `ldd` only works on dynamically linked executables.

(Technically, all Linux `ldd` does is invoke the Linux executable loader, `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, after setting an environment variable. So it should be the most reliable way.)

Some programs might be using `dlopen()` to load libraries, in order to avoid making the program hard-depend on them. For example, Glibc loads NSS libraries that way because their names are only known at run time, not time of compiling/linking.